# How can I make a folder absolutely private?

Tags: office-365, accessibility

I am struggling a bit with this problem. I have full control in my Office 365 environment, but now I want to make a folder only accessible by a certain member, not even for me.

I already made a folder which is private, but I still can acces it, which I don't want for privacy reasons.

Is this possible in Office 365?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are site-collection or web admin, you will always be able to change the permissions back so there is no way to make it *absolutely* private.

If you are a regular member, you will need to give permissions which do not include you.

Sign a NDA maybe? :-)